# Project Template Not Updating on Build

Tags: forms, debugging, project-template

I've been working on a project template today, first time doing so but it has been going alright. I'm almost finished but have now run into some weird issue I can't figure out.

For some reason which I don't know, whenever I try and debug my project template it is now stuck to using some old version of it. No matter what or how much I change then rebuild and try to debug - it still uses some weird old version stuck in some sort of limbo.

I can't seem to figure out where it's finding this file, I've cleared my temp folder. It doesn't show up as installed when I go to Manage Extensions in Visual Studio.

Any ideas what might have happened? There are no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by deleting all files inside `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_cfa111feExp\Extensions`. After doing so, I restarted VS and loaded up my project and **rebuild** *(not build)* the solution.

After that, it now shows the up-to-date version of the project template. What caused this and how to potentially prevent it in the future - I still have absolutely no idea.

I use Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.4.2